# How to get the date value from date control that is placed in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In my ASP.NET project I have one gridview and I have placed the DateControl in gridview using TemplateField. My question is how can I get the Selected Date value? I'm doing my code in VB

My ASP code is

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Release Date" ControlStyle-Width="100">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <uc1:DateControl ID="UCReleaseDate" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And my vb code is (not working)

```
 Dim dtReleaseDate As DateTime
dtReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse(GVMaintainBankChallon.Rows(iGVRowIndex).FindControl  ("UCReleaseDate").ToString)
```

I want to get the Selected Date value in dtReleaseDate variable.. Hope someone will understand this problem and help me..

The gridview image is shown below.

[image]

After selecting the date.

[image]

I want this selected date to codebehind date variable.

Comment: Can you add the code of `DateControl`?

Comment: My date control has written in .ascx file which has large no.of codes. I just add my gridview image in my question.

Comment: Does `DateControl` have a property that returns the date value?

Comment: Yes. It will return the selected date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment below, `DateControl` has a string property named `DateValue`. Assuming that the date is in `MM/dd/yyyy` format, this code should work

```
Dim dateFromControl As String = CType(GVMaintainBankChallon.Rows(iGVRowIndex).FindControl("UCReleaseDate"), DateControl).DateValue

Dim dtReleaseDate As DateTime
dtReleaseDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFromControl, "MM/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ekad. It works fine and it is not SelectedDate, it is DateValue